# SQL Server logging row visits best practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, deadlock

I currently have a database for articles that keeps track of the most read article for a certain amount of time by incrementing the "visits" counter on page_load. The current "visits" counter is a column in the `articles` table (see below):

```
id | title  | description | visits | creation_date
---+--------+-------------+--------+-----------------
1  | test1  | test test.. | 10     | 2019-01-01
2  | test2  | test test.. | 20     | 2019-01-01
```

Sometimes, I experienced connection timeouts and I suspected a deadlock from the "visits" write procedure (database locks if concurrent users were incrementing the same row at once). I thought of the below scenario as an enhancement:

1. Remove the `Visits` counter from the table `Articles`
2. Create a new table `article_visits` with two columns: `article_id` and `date`

**Articles**

```
id | title | desc | creation_date
---+-------+------+---------------
1  | test1 | desd | 2019-01-01
2  | test1 | desd | 2019-01-01
```

**article_visits**

```
article_id | visit_date
-----------+----------------------
1          | 2019-01-01
1          | 2019-01-01
1          | 2019-01-01
1          | 2019-01-01
1          | 2019-01-01
1          | 2019-01-01
2          | 2019-01-01
2          | 2019-01-01
2          | 2019-01-01
```

As an alternative option, once triggering a new visit, I insert a new row into the `articles_visits` table to avoid any deadlocks on the `articles` table. This solution will make the `articles_visits` table grow big very quickly but I don't think table size is a problem.

I would like to know if this is the proper way to log article visits and if the optimization if is a better option than the original solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fine way to record article visits.  It is much less (or not at all) prone to deadlocks, because you are basically just appending new rows.

It is more flexible.  You can get the number of visits between two dates, for instance.  And that can be defined at query time.  You can store the exact time, so determine if there are time preferences for views.

The downside is performance on querying.  If you frequently need the counts, then the calculation can be expensive.

If this is an issue, there are multiple possible approaches:

- A process that summarizes all the data periodically (say data).
- A process that summarizes the data on a period basis for that period (say a daily summary).
- A materialized/indexed view which allows the database to keep the data up-to-date.

Comment: Most of the times a deadlock occurs when a push notification is sent (users access the article at the same time). This could be due to incrementing the "visits" counter correct?
I want to record the most visited articles for the last 7 days. Are you suggesting that I created a "View" that pulls up this data?

Comment: @RamiZebian . . . Your method doesn't quite work for the most visited articles in the last 7 days.  On the 8th day, you need to remove the first day . . . and that gets complicated.  Go with the more detailed solution.  Then only focus on performance improvements if they are needed.

Comment: @Godon Linoff I mean I can get the most viewed in the last 7 days by creating a view that gets the articles while calculating the difference between the current date and the visited date while grouping by Day. The only concern is that articles_visits table will grow very big in size. Would this matter?

Comment: @RamiZebian . . . Given your use-case, you can partition it by day and drop older partitions, limiting the size.

Comment: @Godron Linoff Would it be a good option if I save the article id and the number of visits in one row in the "article_visits" table rather than inserting a new row on every visit? This way, I increment the visit on a separate table

Comment: @RamiZebian . . . Then you are likely to get deadlocks on that table instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly valid, though you may want to do some scoping on how much additional storage and memory load this will require for your database server.

Additionally, I might add a full `datetime` or `datetime2` column for the actual timestamp (in addition to the current date column rather than instead of it, since you'll want to do aggregation by date only and having that value pre-computed can improve performance), and perhaps a few other columns such as IP Address and Referrer. Then you can use this data for additional purposes, such as auditing, tracking referrer/advertiser ROI, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The database size for table "article_visits" won't be a problem? This will increase rapidly in size as a new row is inserted when a page visit is triggered.

Comment: It _might_ be a problem, but you don't know yet. That's why I recommend doing some scoping work. You may find you want to proceed, but that you also need to add a database job to archive data, say, each month. Again, though, you don't know until you do the work to measure how this will impact your system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested to understand why you are getting a dead lock.  It should be the case that a db platform should be able to handle a `update tablename set field = field + 1` concurrently just fine.  Here the table or row will lock and then release but the time should not be long enough to cause a deadlock error.

YOU COULD get a deadlock error if you are updating or locking more than one table with a transaction accross multiple tables esp. if you do them in a different order.

So the question is... in your original code are you linking to multiple tables when you do the update statement?  The solution could be as simple as making your update atomic to one table.

However, I do agree -- the table you describe is a more functional design.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Exactly, the update query is the same you stated: update tablename set field = field + 1 where id=@id. In my case, if am only working with one table "articles". On page load, I execute the query that gets the article details (SELECT title, desc from article where id=@id) and increment the visits counter. When multiple users visit the article at the same time, I experience a connection timeout issue. The only thing i suspected is the "visits" counter because it locks the table until the counter is incremented.

Comment: @RamiZebian if you do a select and then an update as you describe that could cause a deadlock -- if you just a single update as your first statement then it will not (you can also use a platform specific hint to not lock the table on the select and you should be fine but then you risk missing counts in your updates.)

Comment: on every page load I am performing a SELECT followed by an UPDATE in the same connection. But why would it cause a deadlock? Would saving the visits in a separate table solve the problem or at least is considered a better option?

Comment: @RamiZebian -- we can talk more about it here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200850/help-with-question

Answer (score 0):

Current `Articles` table  is not in `Normalized form`.

I will say putting `visits` column in `Articles` table is not proper way of 
`De-Normalization`.

Current `Articles` table is not only giving you deadlock issue but also you cannot get so many other type of Report.
`Daily Visit Report, Weekly Visit Report`.

Creating `Article_visits` table is very good move .
It will be very frequently updated.

My `Article_visits` design

```
article_visit_id |   article_id | visit_date           | visit_count
-----------------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------
1                |    1         | 2019-01-01           | 6
2                |    2         | 2019-01-01           | 3
```

Here `Article_Visit_id` is `int identity(1,1)` which is also `Clustered Index`.

```
Create NonClustered Index NCI_Articleid_date ON Article_visits(article_id,visit_date)
GO
```

In short ,creating CI on `article_id,visit_date` will expensive affair.

If record do not exists for that `article` on that date then insert with `visit_count` 1
if it exists then update `visit_count` i.e. increase by 1.

1. It is  Normalized.
2. You can create any kind of report, current requirement+ any future requirement.
3. You can show Article wise count.Query is so easy and Performant.
4. You can  get weekly ,even getting yearly report is so easy and without 
   `Indexed View`.

Actual Table Design,

```
Create Table Article(Articleid int identity(1,1) primary key
,title varchar(100) not null,Descriptions varchar(max) not null
 ,CreationDate Datetime2(0))
    GO

 Create Table Article_Visit(Article_VisitID int identity(1,1) primary key,Articleid int not null ,Visit_Date datetime2(0) not null,Visit_Count int not null) 
    GO

--Create Trusted FK
    ALTER TABLE Article_Visit
    WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Articleid FOREIGN KEY(Articleid) 
    REFERENCES Article(Articleid) NOT FOR REPLICATION;
    GO


    --Create NonClustered Index NCI_Articleid_Date on 
    -- Article_Visit(Articleid,Visit_Date)
    --Go

    Create NonClustered Index NCI_Articleid_Date1 on 
     Article_Visit(Visit_Date)include(Articleid)
    Go
```

Create Trusted FK to get Index Seek Benefit (in short).
I think ,`NCI_Articleid_Date` is no more require because of`Articleid` being `Trusted FK` .

`Deadlock Issue`: `Trusted FK` was also created to overcome Deadlock issue. 
It often occur due to bad `Application code` or `UN-Optimized Sql query` or `Bad Table Design`.Beside this also there several other valid reason,like handling `Race Condition`.It is quite DBA thing.If deadlock is hurting too much then after addressing above reason, you may have to `Isolation Level`.

Many Deadlock issue are auto handle by Sql server itself.

There are so many article online on [DEADLOCK REASON](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/community/solarwinds-community/geek-speak/blog/2016/06/18/the-cause-of-every-deadlock-in-sql-server).

> I don't think table size is a problem

`Table size` are big issue.Chances of `Deadlock` in both design are very very less.But you will always face other `demerit` of `Big Size` table.

I am telling you to read few more article.

I hope that this is your exactly same real table with same data type ?

How frequently both table will inserted/updated ?

Which table will be query more frequently ?

Concurrent use of each table.

Deadlock can be only minimize so that there is no performance issue or transaction issue.

> What is relation between `Visitorid` and `Artcileid` ?

Comment: Won't this cause a deadlock on the Article_visits table you created while updating the visit_count?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If you check this answer. I did not know that a Trusted FK can overcome DeadLock. Also, I totally agree regarding the table design. However, if you check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58378589/6859050 the poster says that you are likely to get deadlocks on the other table instead. How true is that?

Comment: @RamiZebian , Don't think that only design will help you remove Deadlock.Chance of deadlock can by only minimize.Read my edited.